# How to add and then display images urls from database in Laravel/Backpack CRUD?

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I can upload files with special field upload_multiply and then save their names in DB, but how to print them back when editing the record? I use one-to-many relation, database structure like **objects** and **objects_images**, where exist object_id, name and url of uploaded image. Im using Laravel 5.4.

Now my code is very typicall:

I have a **ObjectCrudController** where i build form for my project. I use buildt-in Backpack/CRUD fields like this (for categories):

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'label' => 'Category to display',
            'type' => 'select',
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'entity' => 'category',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => 'App\Models\Category',
            'wrapperAttributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-group col-md-4'
            ]
        ]);
```

But I cant understand how to upload some images and then display their records as miniatures, also i need an ability to remove already uploaded image record. I think there can be used something like **html field** or **view** from backpack CRUD, but i don't know where to start.

Comment: please share some code you have done.

Comment: done. added some. thanks.

Comment: 1. you need to create the miniature when you upload 2. make a custom field in resources/vendor/backpack/base/views/fields if needed 3. please share your question here in n doubt: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD It's like 1am for me, but i'll give you a proper answer in the morning